# Looping through a list and get the corresponding variable out of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a list

```
selection = ['Argentina', 'Belize', 'Bolivia', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia',
'Costa Rica', 'Cuba', 'Dominican Republic', 'Ecuador', 'Guatemala', 'Guyana',
'Honduras', 'Haiti', 'Latin America & Caribbean' 'St. Martin (French part)',
'Mexico', 'Nicaragua', 'Panama', 'Peru', 'Puerto Rico', 'Paraguay', 'El Salvador',
'Suriname', 'Uruguay', 'Venezuela, RB']
```

and a dataframe `data_selected` containing all countries and values for each of them per year.

[image]

Now I want to loop through the list, get the values specific for every country and plot a line (like shown below).

[image]

My approach is the following:

```
sns.set(font_scale=5)

    
nrow=4 ; ncol=6 ;


fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(nrows=nrow, ncols=ncol, 
                            figsize=(100,60),
                            gridspec_kw=
                            {'wspace':0.02,
                                'hspace':0.3,
                                })
 
list_ax=ax_array.flatten()

pal=sns.color_palette('PuOr_r', 15)


for ax, data_selected, p in zip(list_ax.flatten(), selection, pal):
     sns.lineplot(data_selected, cmap=pal,
                annot=True, 
                fmt='.1f',
                annot_kws={
                'multialignment':'center',
                'size':'small'
                },
                cbar_kws={
                'orientation':'horizontal',
                      },
                  ax=ax)
```

But it takes "Argentina" as **x** and *not* as **y**. How to change that ?

Answer (score 1):

according to your code data_selected is not the data, how about:

```
for ax, data, p in zip(list_ax.flatten(), data_selection[selection], pal):

     sns.lineplot(data, cmap=pal,
                annot=True, 
                fmt='.1f',
                annot_kws={
                'multialignment':'center',
                'size':'small'
                },
                cbar_kws={
                'orientation':'horizontal',
                      },
                  ax=ax)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Could you explain to me why my code does not take my dataframe? I would be very grateful.
I get an error message stating that df is not defined. Do you know how I can avoid that error? Should I just create an empty dataframe?

Comment: you should replace df with your actual dataset whose columns are selection. df here is just a placeholder.

Comment: The actual dataframe is called data_selected. :)

Comment: in that case, try the edited code. I edited the solution